# Contribution of Leigh Eddings

Tags: david-eddings, leigh-eddings

Do we know how much or what exactly Leigh Eddings' contributions were to the Belgariad, Malloreon, Elenium, and Tamuli? Did David provide a reason why she was not initially credited for the works? Also, do newer editions/reprints now credit both of them?

Comment: IIRC *Belgarath the Sorcerer* (the first-published book to be jointly credited) has a Foreword that touches on this, but I'm far away from my copy to check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't, exactly. Some of David Eddings' statements, though, suggest she was truly a co-author, or at least a co-contributor, throughout his career. Of course, these contributions may have come more in the form of ideas than exact words, which may be one reason she was not credited the entire time.

I'm not sure he ever provided an exact reason why she was not always credited. It's possible that it was because it **was** more contribution-of-ideas rather than actual writing. Then, too, there was still a strong sexism in SF&F publishing when Eddings started publishing *The Belgariad*, which may have led him or his publisher to conclude it was better to use only his name.

Newer editions continue to credit only David Eddings, as far as I've seen, except of course on those books where Leigh was already credited.

Comment: Thank you. Did she take on a more active writing role in *Dreamers* and *Althalus*?

Comment: Again, it's hard to say. Certainly, she's credited as co-author, but whether that's because she's actually **wrote** or because David decided that her contributions of ideas were long-since enough to get her credit is hard to say. I'm not sure he ever said anything more definite than that he didn't feel he could have written any of it without her input as well as her support.

Comment: David explicitly states that she was part of the effort from the very beginning in Belgarath the Sorcerer. The Rivan Codex gives further detail in what she was good at developing and how they complemented each other.

Answer (score 3):

I can't remember where I read it (probably in the preface of one of the co-credited books), but I remember David Eddings specifically saying that Leigh was very good at creating names and that she's responsible for most of the character/place names in the Belgaraid and Malloreon.

Comment: Probably the Rivan Codex.

Comment: Definitely the Rivan Codex